# Why am I getting "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I am attempting to call an asynchronous method. The asynchronous method is:

```
async connect() {
        this.pool = await mysql.createPool(this.conf);
        await this.pool.getConnection().catch((err) => { throw new Error(err) });
}
```

The code that calls this method is:

```
(async () => {
    await db.connect()
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(`Database connection error: ${err.message}`);
            throw new Error(err);
        });
})();
```

However, when an error occurs within the this.pool.getConnection(), I am getting the following warning(s):

```
[Thu Jun 13 2019 23:10:59] [ERROR]  (node:18296) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
    at pool.getConnection.catch
    at process._tickCallback
[Thu Jun 13 2019 23:10:59] [ERROR]  (node:18296) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
[Thu Jun 13 2019 23:10:59] [ERROR]  (node:18296) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Having read the answers to similar questions, I understand that rejections from Promises must be handled, but I am lost as to where I have not correctly handled this. The this.pool.getConnection() call has a catch block, and in there I am throwing the error so it gets passed to the anonymous calling function to handle.

I've tried several variations on this code, including adding a catch block to the anonymous function itself and throwing the error again there, but nothing seems to work and the warning always originates at the this.pool.getConnection() call.

What I am trying to achieve is for any error occuring within the connect() method to be passed up to the anonymous function to handle.

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** interestingly, if I write the this.pool.getConnection() line as follows (with nothing in the catch block), the warning disappears:

```
await this.pool.getConnection().catch((err) => {});
```

The moment I attempt to do anything inside the arrow function, e.g. assigning the error to a variable, the warning resurfaces.

Comment: I don't see exactly what the issue is, but don't do `.catch((err) => { throw new Error(err) });`, that's completely pointless.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. My (flawed, it seems) understanding was that I needed the catch there to avoid the very warnings I'm getting, and that I needed to throw the error again to allow the calling anonymous function to catch and handle it.

Comment: Thrown errors propagate back up asynchronous functions very similarly to how they propagate back up synchronous functions. The magic is in the keyword `await`: it transforms a resolved promise into an expression whose value is the result that was resolved, and it transforms a rejected promise into a thrown error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code you are not handling an error:

```
(async () => {
    await db.connect()
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error(`Database connection error: ${err.message}`);
            throw new Error(err);
        });
})();
```

If `db.connect()` rejects, then your `.catch()` will get called and it will rethrow.  That means the `await db.connect()` will see a rejected promise and your wrapper async function will return a rejected promise which you have no handler for.  Thus you get an unhandled rejection.

You can either make it so the error is entirely handled within your `async` function and thus is never returns a rejected promise or you can handle the error properly.

FYI, it's also odd (and generally not recommended) to mix `await` with `.catch()`.  Usually you use `.then()` and `.catch()` together and `await` with `try/catch`.

---

If all the error handling you want is to log the error and avoid the warning, then you can change to this:

```
db.connect().catch((err) => {
    console.error(`Database connection error: ${err.message}`);
    // put any other required error handling here
});
```

By removing the `throw err`, you "handle" the error locally and thus there is no unhandled rejection.  The only rejection you have here is handled.  Also, note there appears to be no need for `async` or `await` since you're just making a function call and handling any exception.

---

Note, the design pattern of:

```
async function foo() {
    await f();
}
```

is pretty much the same as:

```
function foo() {
    return f();
}
```

The only places where it would be different is if `f()` didn't return a promise or threw synchronously, both of which should never happen in a properly behaved promise-returning API.

Since I prefer the simplest code expression that accomplishes your goals, I prefer to not use `async/await` except when it actually helps you make the code simpler.

Comment: Thanks, some interesting points as to correct/best practice. Unfortunately, removing the throw from the db.connect() catch block doesn't get rid of the warning, as I understood from your answer it should. I may be wrong, but if the issue was as you described, wouldn't my UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning refer to the anonymous function rather than this.pool.getConnection()?

Comment: @Rob - Are you 100% sure you're using one of my recommended blocks of code exactly as I show it?  For further help, you will have to troubleshoot exactly where the warning is coming from.  I assumed it was coming from the promise returned from your anonymous function (as a rejection to that promise is not handled at all), but if it's also coming from somewhere else, you may have to fix something else too.

Comment: I did, I copied your first suggested form for the anonymous function - but the stack trace has changed. I'm wondering if the true issue lies within the mysql2 module I'm using, as it all now refers to files within /node_modules/mysql2 and not any of my code.

Comment: @Rob - OK, I removed that first block of code since the anonymous function is simply not needed any more.  I can't tell from here if the anonymous function was part of the issue or if they issue is inside of the mysql2 module.

Comment: @Rob - I do notice that you have no `.then()` handler on the `db.connect()` so your code has no way of knowing when the connect succeeded.  Are you sure you aren't trying to use the connection (later in your code) before it has finished connecting?

Comment: I'm not using the connection anywhere. My code now looks like this: [link](https://pastebin.com/asR3BQmz), and the stack trace I'm getting is: [link](https://pastebin.com/GJkgQmn9) - the line it refers to in mysql.js (18) is where I'm throwing the error inside the catch block of connect().

Comment: @Rob - It looks internal to mySQL at mysql.js:18:19.  If I had the code in front of me, my next step would be to trace into that function call (or set a breakpoint in it) and see exactly what's happening to find out where exactly  the unhandled rejection is originating.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that although my code was not in any way ideal, the true source of the issue was that I was calling db.connect() from somewhere else in addition to within the anonymous function. This other call had no catch block for error handling, thus the UnhandledPromiseRejection warning. Once I removed this duplicate call to db.connect(), the warning disappeared.

For reference, here is the working code improved with the help of contributors in the comments/answers:

Method within the database class:

```
async connect() {
    this.pool = await mysql.createPool(this.conf);
    return await this.pool.getConnection();
}
```

And the call to it:

```
db.connect()
  .then(result => {
      console.log(result)
  })
  .catch(err => {
      console.error(`Database connection error: ${err.message}`);
  });
```